# Remove scroll in Listview

Tags: android, listview

There are only two items in my listview and it covers half of screen but listview still shows scroll around it. I have set height to wrap_content

[image]

layout code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listLikeWhatsapp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
        />    

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't want scroll to appear on listview because it will have only two items and there is no need to show. I am not sure what is causing scroll to appear.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanking you in advance

**UPDATE**

Here is my row item xml :

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"

    android:background="@drawable/roundedshape"
    android:alpha="0.7">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:contentDescription="desc"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_insert_emoticon_black_48dp"

        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Assignments"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#000"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/last_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:text="Last Update : 01-01-2017"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="#696969"/>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unread_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="04"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circular"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to add the android:layout_height="match_parent" in place of wrap_content

Comment: Well i want to add textview below this listview. By applying match_parent will not show textview below.Correct ?

Comment: 1. try not to use `fill_parent`. 2. Can you upload xml of row items?

Comment: fill_parent and match_parent works the same way. Only difference is, your app will not work in Most of the devices if you use fill_parent

Comment: And for your text view issue, first align text view to the bottom of the screen, then give match parent to list, and use the attribute `layout_above` to show both list and text view

Comment: **I don't want scroll to appear on listview because it will have only two items and there is no need to show. I am not sure what is causing scroll to appear.**

Why aint you including the layout inside your LinearLayout then?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

to hide the scrollbar

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listLikeWhatsapp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"     // add this
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
    />
```

or in your code:

```
yourlistView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

To disable Scrolling of `listview` Items try:

```
    listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            return true; //  Action will not be forwarded
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

OR

```
yourListView.setScrollContainer(false);
```

Comment: Well it didn't show scroll bar by applying your code. But it is still scroll able.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ListView
...
android:scrollbars="none"
...
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding:

```
 android:scrollbars="none"
```

Answer (score 1):

user android:scrollbar="none" like this;

```
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view_meals_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Comment: By applying match parent, it covers the complete screen. I want to add textview below that listing

Answer (score 1):

To hide scrollbars
do this

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

To disable scrolling do this

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
    }
});
```

PS: I think you have messed up your item view which includes icon title and description.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code .....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="your text view"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/text_ap"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listLikeWhatsapp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/text_ap"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question i was searching for solution and i remembered that i use it in another project and i forgot the owner of the solution so here is the code :

```
public static void justifyListViewHeightBasedOnChildren (ListView listView) {

        ListAdapter adapter = listView.getAdapter();

        if (adapter == null) {
            return;
        }
        ViewGroup vg = listView;
        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = adapter.getView(i, null, vg);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams par = listView.getLayoutParams();
        par.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (adapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(par);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```